# Stripes resource bundles in different JARs

Tags: java, tomcat, bundle, stripes

I'm making a web app on Tomcat server using Stripes.
Application has multiple modules, each of them is localized through its own `StripesResources.properties` file. Every module is packaged into a JAR file under `WEB-INF/lib`.

```
WEB-INF/lib
|- moduleA.jar
|  |- com.some.package
|  |  |- ModuleA.class
|  |- StripesResources.properties
|- moduleB.jar
|  |- com.some.package
|  |  |- ModuleB.class
|  |- StripesResources.properties
```

The problem is that the only StripesResources file gets loaded. I figured out that resources are loaded by the system ClassLoader, which seems to load the first file with that name it finds.

What is the best practice of using multiple resources?

- Should I give these resource files different names?
- or Is there any way for some class to use .properties from the JAR it has been loaded from?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As I have figured out, Stripes does not support multiple resource bundles (though it allows to use separate files for error messages and form labels). So I decided to implement my own `LocalizationBundleFactory` that would load all the `*.properties` files with a given name using [`ClassLoader.getResources(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResources%28java.lang.String%29).

Source code sketch for the solution will be posted soon.